# How to Extract the list value having the multiple classes using selenium in java

Tags: java, selenium

HTML Code

```
<div id="">
  <div class="widthFull floatLEFT">
    <div class="class-left-first">
      <div class="txt-left">
        <ul class="FuelBullet bulletedArrow">
          <li><a href=""></a></li>
          <li><a href=""></a></li>
          <li><a href=""></a></li>
          <li><a href=""></a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="class-left">
     <div class="txt-left">
       <ul class="FuelBullet bulletedArrow">
         <li><a href=""></a></li>
         <li><a href=""></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-left">
    <div class="txt-left">
      <ul class="FuelBullet bulletedArrow">
        <li><a href=""></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="widthFull floatLEFT">
     ....same as above ...
  </div>
  <div class="widthFull floatLEFT">
    ....same as above ...
  </div>
</div>
```

My tried Code.

```
WebElement ele= driver.findElement(By.id("CPH1_DisplayAllSupportedCities_PanelAllCities"));
List<WebElement> ele1=ele.findElements(By.className("widthFull floatLEFT"));

for(WebElement Element : ele1){
            List<WebElement> ele2=Element.findElements(By.className("txt-left"));
       for(WebElement txt : ele2){
                 List<WebElement> ele3=txt.findElements(By.className("FuelBullet bulletedArrow"));
           for(WebElement list : ele3){
                List<WebElement> e1=list.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
                     for(WebElement link : e1){
                     System.out.println(link.getAttribute("href"));
                     }
                 }
             }
```

I have to extract the list of `href` value from above sample. I have tried above code, but it didn't get work for me.

Please Help..!!!

Comment: Could you share the screenshot or html of the elements you're accessing here.

Comment: yes, i also link my html content and java code above

Comment: Just add all the values to a `List<String> hrefValues` instead of where you're doing  `System.out.println(link.getAttribute("href"));`

Comment: i have to add but not shows the output 
for(WebElement link : e1){
             String str= link.getAttribute("href");
                        System.out.println(str);
            }
its shows the error using list<strings>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem here is that, the By.className accepts only one class name at a time. We can not use like By.className("widthFull floatLEFT"). 
We can use either one class name like, `By.className("widthFull")` or `By.className("floatLEFT")`.

if you want to use both class names then, you can go with other type of locator like css selector or xpath as given below.

```
WebElement ele= driver.findElement(By.id("CPH1_DisplayAllSupportedCities_PanelAllCities"));
List<WebElement> ele1=ele.findElements(By.cssSelector(".widthFull.floatLEFT"));

for(WebElement Element : ele1){
       List<WebElement> ele2=Element.findElements(By.className("txt-left"));
       for(WebElement txt : ele2){
           List<WebElement> ele3=txt.findElements(By.cssSelector(".FuelBullet.bulletedArrow"));
           for(WebElement list : ele3){
                List<WebElement> e1=list.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
                for(WebElement link : e1){
                   System.out.println(link.getAttribute("href"));
                }
            }
       }
  }
```